# Mirror is going in different direction

Tags: mirror

Im made the half model and when im using mirror modifier its going little bit off the direction it should be.Im using reference image. with the reference image i have made the half model and when mirror the reference image not match. Any suggestion or help Thanks
[image]

**Without Mirror**

[image]

**Mirror Modifier**

[image]

**Not mirror perfect**

[image]

**Reference image**

[image]

Comment: Hard to say completely as you did not pack the reference image in the blend file, but two things: the rotation around Z should be applied and then you may tune the rotation/position of the vertices (to do that snap the 3D cursor to the object origin and set the 3D cursor as pivot point)

Comment: @lemon sorry i forgot to attach the reference image now its update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is you have rotated the mesh in order to align it to the reference image.

But this is difficult to do that **and** to align the mesh with its origin (which is used by the mirror as point of symmetry).

Generally, reference images are rotated and scaled *before* so that they are aligned to the 3D view axis.

But you can correct it:

- Reset the Z rotation to 0°
- Snap the 3D cursor at the object origin (in object mode, having the mesh selected: <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> then 'cursor to origin')
- Enter edit mode
- Activate the mirror
- Set the 3D cursor as pivot point
- Select all the vertices
- And try to rotate/move the vertices so that the mirrored part is well aligned and mirrored

Once done, come back to object mode and rotate to check if your mesh is OK comparing to the reference.

Your blend file, a bit (but not perfectly) corrected : 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Before using the mirror modifier you need to apply the rotation.

[image]

Next set up your background image correctly. The image of the pliers need to be rotated a few degrees.

[image]

When you have your background image correct, in Edit mode rotate your pliers to fit.

Also, only half of your circular (axis part) part should be meshed.The other half will be created by the Mirror modifier.

Comment: Thanks for replying many be few min you were late to reply.